# Using SMS Receiver

Tags: android

An application that automatically listens for SMS messages containing some secret code. Once that message is received, you can call on a number from which sms is received automatically. Whenever i send message Dial it does nothing. Even toast is not showing.

```
public class Receiving extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SmsMessage[] sms = null;

    Bundle bundle = Intent.getExtras();

    String str = " SMS From : ";
    if (bundle != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        sms = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {

            sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            if (i == 0) {
                str +=  sms[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += ":";
            }
            str += sms[i].getMessageBody().toString();
if (sms[i].getMessageBody().equals("Dial")) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

                    in.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ sms[i].getOriginatingAddress()));

                    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(in2);                 }

Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What intent filters do you use?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml                                                `<activity
       android:name="com.example.sms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>  
        <receiver android:name="com.example.sms.Receiving">
          <intent-filter >
 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>` @JakubSzczygieł

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i already have attached permissions for receive sms as well send sms and also for call_phone. I have specified Send_SMS permission as i am sending SMS in MainActivity.java file.@JakubSzczygie

Comment: can i use any other actions rather than just call? If yes, can you suggest me some actions. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of action would you like to achive?

Comment: silent mode to ringer mode or shut down or switch on of device. I read these can be done but when i tried to find an action related to these but there were none.